# Product rule for matrix-valued and vector-valued functions

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

Given $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ how can we compute $\nabla (g(x)f(x))$?

Comment: Can you see how to expand $\partial_i(g_{ij}f_j)$ by the product rule? (See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product).)

Comment: If you can find $\mathrm d(gf),$ then you should be able to extract what you need. Note that the order would be of importance here, since commutativity fails. Hence what you should have is $$g\mathrm df+\mathrm dg f.$$ I couldn't do that now, otherwise I would have expanded this out and written it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $(i,j)$-term of $\nabla(fg)$ is given by
\begin{align}
\partial_i((g(x)f(x))_j) &= \partial_i\left(\sum_{k=1}^n g_{kj}(x)f_k(x)\right)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n (\partial_ig_{kj})(x)f_k(x) + \sum_{k=1}^n g_{kj}(x)(\partial_i f_k)(x)\\
&= ((\partial_ig)(x)f(x))_j + (g(x)(\partial_i f)(x))_j
\end{align}
so
\begin{align*}
\nabla(g(x)f(x)) &= \begin{bmatrix} \partial_i((g(x)f(x))_j)\end{bmatrix}_{i,j=1}^n \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} (\partial_1 g)(x)f(x)\\ \vdots \\ (\partial_n g)(x)f(x)\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} g(x)(\partial_1f)(x)\\ \vdots \\ g(x)(\partial_nf)(x)\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix} (\partial_1 g)(x)f(x)\\ \vdots \\ (\partial_n g)(x)f(x)\end{bmatrix} + g(x)(\nabla f(x))^T
\end{align*}
where $(\partial_i g)(x)$ is $\partial_i$ applied to the matrix $g$ elementwise.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think the last equation needs some changes:

$$\nabla(g(x)f(x)) = \begin{bmatrix} (\partial_1 g)(x)f(x) & \cdots & (\partial_n g)(x)f(x)\end{bmatrix}^T + (\nabla f)(x)g(x)^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n},$$

am I right?

Comment: @darkmoor I disagree. How did you get that?

Comment: We know for specific $x$ that $\nabla f \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and $g \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ so $g(x)\nabla f(x)$ do not commute. Then based on your answer I have tried to see it analytically and I concluded to the previous comment.

Comment: @darkmoor You are right. Have a look now.

Comment: The matrix $\nabla (g(x)f(x))$ is symmetric?

Comment: @darkmoor If $f,g \in C^2$ then yes.

Comment: Sorry again, just to be sure, in the last equation, in the first part, the terms $(\partial_i g)(x)f(x)\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ shouldn't be placed in columns?

Comment: @darkmoor I believe not, it is $$\begin{bmatrix} ((\partial_ig)(x)f(x))_j\end{bmatrix}_{i,j=1}^n = \begin{bmatrix}[((\partial_1 g)(x)f(x))_j]_{j=1}^n \\ \vdots \\ [((\partial_n g)(x)f(x))_j]_{j=1}^n \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's use a convention in which an uppercase Latin letter denotes a matrix and a lowercase letter denotes a vector.

Since you've told us nothing about the functions $(f,G)\,$ I'll assume that you are able to calculate their gradients without any difficulties
$$\eqalign{
g &= {\rm vec}(G) \\
A &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
&\quad\implies\quad
&df = A\,dx,\quad
\\
B &= \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
&\quad\implies
&dg = B\,dx,\quad 
\\
}$$
The product of the two function is a vector, whose gradient can be calculated (with the aid of the [Kronecker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations) product).
$$\eqalign{
 h &= Gf \;\,=\; (f^T\otimes I_n)\,g \\
dh &=  G\,df + (f^T\otimes I_n)\,dg \\
   &= GA\,dx + (f^T\otimes I_n)B\,dx \\
\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}
   &= GA + (f^T\otimes I_n)B \\
}$$